# SensorManager TYPE_STEP_COUNTER get value without trigger an Event

Tags: android, service, sensormanager

I use this piece of code to get the steps on a android 4.4.2 device.

```
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
mStepCounter = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);

mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorEventListenerCounter,
            mStepCounter, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

I use an EventListener to get the values while the app is running. Now I want to get the init step value when I start my app. Because the counter starts at 0 only with the restart of the device. So the value is always over in my case 0. For calculations I need to know the start value.

This is the code I use at runtime to get the value when it changes.

```
private SensorEventListener mSensorEventListenerCounter = new SensorEventListener() {

@Override
  public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
}

@Override
  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    value = event.values[0];
  }
};
```

**Is there a way to catch the value, without trigger an Event by shaking the phone once to imitate a step?**

Thanks.

Comment: How about just saving the value the first time onSensorChanged is called and storing that as your 0 value?

Comment: This is what I do right now. But I want to save the value directly when the user opens the app in the onCreate part. The Problem is, when the user activates my app, he can be sitting. And I want that it already gets the right counter to see allways the steps depending on time.

Can I push a onSensorChanged Event by myself?

Comment: Its a function, of course you can call it yourself.  But you wouldn't have the right initial data to pass it.  My best suggestion would be to have a flag in your app that tells whether you have seen an initial value or not, and to provide special case logic for when that flag is false.  For example, display 0 steps taken if you've never seen an onSensorChanged call.

Comment: So the only way to access this values is over the event? Damn. Then I will set my int initValue to -100. Then I can for sure say that it´s not overwritten yet.